# Why does text appear in browsers but not appear in image viewers?

Tags: svg

I am trying to render a chart but encounter a problem: The `<text>` elements appear in browsers (Chrome, Firefox) but not in traditional image viewers (Eyes of GNOME, GIMP, Inkscape).

[Code](https://github.com/KSXGitHub/parallel-disk-usage-0.0.0-benchmarks/blob/0864d198a414a49ab8238ec47d4e3cbe74646671/tmp.benchmark-report.competing.blksize.svg?short_path=31e29e3)

[image]

At first, I thought that it was because image viewers are incapable of rendering fonts, until I came across an asciinema's thumbnail, which is displayed perfectly by Eyes of GNOME:

[image: an asciinema's thumbnail]

**Question:** Why does this happen and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is in nested SVGs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg ... >
  <rect ... />
  <svg ... >
    <text ... >pdu --quantity=blksize tmp.sample</text>
  </svg>
  ...
</svg>
```

Move your text elements to the root svg and you will be able to see them in the image viewers / editors (tested with Inkscape and GNOME image viewer)

Comment: I am not an expert in SVG. The reason I have nested `svg` tags is to line up the text to the same level as corresponding bars. If I was to move the `text` elements out, is there a way to line them up perfectly with the bars regardless of font sizes? (btw, the svg image was generated, not written by hand)

Comment: You can put `<text>` under a `<g>` element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g

Comment: It is a bad idea to nest SVG's. Use g elements and transforms to position your content